# Smallest integer \$n\$ such that \$\frac{\sqrt{\log_2{n}}}{(\log_2 {\log_2 n})^2} > 1\$

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source

Write code that outputs the smallest integer \$n > 5\$ such that \$\frac{\sqrt{\log_2{n}}}{(\log_2 {\log_2 n})^2} > 1\$. Your code may have at most one digit in its source code.  You can use your chosen digit more than once however.

By digits we are only counting the ASCII characters between 0x30 and 0x39 (inclusive).

Comment: @Dingus I had the bound wrong for \$n\$. Fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: What counts as a digit?

Comment: @Neil Any of 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: By digits are we only counting the ASCII characters between 0x30 and 0x39 (inclusive) or any character that resembles a digit? For example, is [`⁹²2*‘`](https://tio.run/#%23y0rNyan8//9R485Dm4y0HjXM@P8fAA) a valid Jelly solution?

Comment: @NickKennedy I think that's valid

Comment: The value is equal to `ackermann(4, 2) + 4`.

Comment: This is excluding all languages that can't do any better than double precision.

Comment: @Philippos it doesn't exclude them. It just means their code will be more work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 22 bytes

```python
print(-~2**2**2**2**2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwU3dzNyC_KISheLKYi4g1itOLYnPzCuJz02siC8uKYpPyUzPLCnWMDQAAc2lpSVpuhbbCoqASjR064y0tBAIKrkASkFpAA)

[According to WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sqrt%28log2%28x%29%29%2Flog2%28log2%28x%29%29%5E2%3D1), the equation \$\sqrt{\log_2(x)} = \log_2(\log_2(x))^2\$ has three solutions. Two real numbers around 1 and 5 and a very large integer solution. So what is that large integer solution?

simple transformations on both sides yield
$$
\log_2(x)^{\frac 1 4} = \log_2(\log_2(x)) \\
2^{2^{log2(x)^{1/4}}} = x
$$
Now, lets substitute \$y=log2(x)^{1/4}\$. Note that \$y\$ has to be an integer as well. This yields two equations:
$$
2^{2^y} = x, \quad y=\log_2(x)^{\frac 1 4} \\
2^{2^y} = x, \quad y^4=\log_2(x) \\
2^{2^y} = x, \quad 2^{y^4}=x \\
2^{2^y} = 2^{y^4} \\
2^y = y^4 \\
$$

The only integer solution to this is \$y=16\$, leaving us with \$x=2^{16^4}=2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}\$. The first integer that satisfies the inequality is \$x+1\$.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + gmp, 25 bytes

```r
gmp::as.bigz(2)^2^2^2^2+T
```

[Try it at RDRR!](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=gmp%3A%3Aas.bigz(2)%5E2%5E2%5E2%5E2%2BT)

Port of [@ovs’ Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267396/42248), so be sure to upvote that one too! R has no native bigint support so this needs the gmp package.

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 29 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 3.625 bytes

```
k₴E›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwia+KCtEXigLoiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Bitstring:

```
10000100001000010110011010000
```

Port of the python answer, but without any digits at all.

### Explained

```
k₴E›­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
k₴E   # ‎⁡2 ** 65536
   ›  # ‎⁢+ 1
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 21 bytes

*-1 thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)*

The only (decimal) digit used in the source is `0`.

```javascript
_=>-~(-~0n>>~0xFFFFn)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1k63TkO3ziDPzq7OoMINCPI0/yfn5xXn56Tq5eSna6RpaGr@BwA)

This computes \$1+2^{1+65535}\$

---

With all the BigInt suffixes and extra parentheses due to a different operator precedence, a direct port of [ovs' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267396/58563) would be **25 bytes**:

```javascript
_=>-~(2n**2n**2n**2n**2n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1k63TsMoT0sLFWv@T87PK87PSdXLyU/XSNPQ1PwPAA)

Comment: `<<-~0xFFFFn` => `>>~0xFFFFn`

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language(Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98oDgq1jfSN/v//r1tQlJlXAgA)

```mathematica
2^2^2^2^2+2/2
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
Ｉ⊕Ｘ²Ｘ⁴¦⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzMvuSg1NzWvJDVFIyC/PLVIw0hHAcIw0VGw0AQB6////@uW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   ²        Literal integer `2`
  Ｘ         Raised to power
     ⁴      Literal integer `4`
    Ｘ       Raised to power
       ⁸    Literal integer `8`
 ⊕          Incremented
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

10 bytes using only one superscript digit:

```
Ｉ⊕Ｘ²Ｘ⊗²⊗⊗²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzMvuSg1NzWvJDVFIyC/PLVIw0hHAcJwyS9NygEKG2nqKMDYCDEIsP7//79uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: As above, but uses `Doubled` (`⊗`) to make `4` and `8` from `2`. (A port of @ovs' Python solution would have been 12 bytes.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
⁹²2*‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R485Dm4y0HjXM@P8fAA)

Port of [@ovs’ Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267396/42248), so be sure to upvote that one too! The superscript digits are permitted as per reply to comment from @Simd (the OP).

### Explanation

```
⁹     | 256
 ²    | Squared
  2*  | 2 to the power of this
    ‘ | +1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 14 bytes

```hs
succ$2^2^2^2^2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzv7g0OVnFKA4K/@cmZuYp2CoUFGXmlSik/f@XnJaTmF78Xze5oAAA)

Port of @ovs [python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267396/84844)

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 5 bytes

```
¥:*Ë→
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FisPLbXSOtz9qG3SkuKk5GKoKEwWAA)

```
¥:*Ë→
¥       Push 256
 :      Duplicate
  *     Multiply
   Ë    Power of 2
    →   Increment
```

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 12

```
2dddd^^^^z+p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98oBQjigKBKu@D/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 14 bytes

[image: code with non ascii character]

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/99I/f3@/RmuGfoK/goOXP//AwA)

The trailing new line is required
I'm using a screenshot as the non ascii character gets removed on save

Port of [lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)'s [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267397/97729)

Explanation:

```
2                Pushes 2 on the stack
 '0xFFFF         Pushes 65535 on the stack
   h             Increment the top of the stack
    E            Pop y, pop x, push x^y
     h           Increment the top of the stack
      / O @      Output and exit
```

Same byte count using `Ā` for \$256 * 256 = 65536\$

```
2'Ā.*Eh/ O @
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/99I/UiDnpZrhr6Cv4ID1///AA)

Comment: Is one of 2 and 0 not  an ASCII  character?

Comment: @Simd if you are referring to the `0xFFFF` in the explanation, I just use it as a placeholder to show the value of the unprintable character, otherwise the other `O` stands for `O`utput

Comment: Would `` work instead of `h`? (Same byte count though.)

Comment: (I see what you mean about 0xFFFF being lost...)

Comment: `` would not work, I do not think it is a valid Alice instruction. `h` increments the result by 1 as the desired output is the result of \$2^{65536}+1\$

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
₁no>
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVNjXr7d//8A)

Without using the superscript number(s) either, it's still 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage):

```
žHo>
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6D6PfLv//wE)

**Explanation:**

```python
₁     # Push builtin 256
 n    # Square it to 65536

žH    # (or alternatively) Push builtin 65536

  o   # Pop and push 2 to the power this 65536
   >  # Increase it by 1
      # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 9 bytes

```
>:^^:*~2x
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT0F9TQFWysFdR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmux0s4qLs5Kq86oAsK_Ga3JlQ5SbmdlVBGnZaWcqMeVAeHH6RvZ6WUChbkS84pBQobaQCVmpqbGZlypyRn5CkBrFIBSEE46MicDwoFYsWABhAYA)

```
>:^^:*~2x
       2x    bigint 2
  ^^:*~      call ^^:* with 2x on both sides:
   ^:          repeat
  ^            2^ (2 is the left argument of ^:)
     *         2*2 times (the 2s are the left and right arguments of ^:)
             the result so far = 2^(2^(2^(2^(2))))
>:           increment
```

Bonus 10 and 11 bytes:

```
>:2x^*:#a.
        a.    a built-in string containing 256 extended ascii chars
       #      length of it (256)
     *:       square
  2x^         raise 2 to the power of that
>:            increment

>:^/2>.i:2x
       i:2x   -2 -1 0 1 2
    2>.       apply max(2, x) to each element; 2 2 2 2 2
  ^/          reduce by ^ from the right; 2^(2^(2^(2^(2))))
>:            increment
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 32 bytes

[image: code with non printable characters]

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f8/OikzPTOvJNbKqiC/XMNQ21DHUFv9/f796tGKhrGa2ob//wMA)

Explanation:

```
                  1+0xFFFF[!1]     # Calculates 65536
[bigint]::pow(1+1,            )    # Calculates 2^65536
                               +1  # Increments by 1 and implicitly prints on stdout
```

Comment: Amazing it has bigint support!

Answer (score 1):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 18 bytes

```
1 1+""S>c1+ ^1+
```

[Try it on scline!](https://scline.fly.dev/##H4sIAEZCd2UCAzNUMNRWer9_v1KwXbKhtkKcoTYAtxgMTBIAAAA#)

Didn't read the question closely x_x.

Comment: *Your code may have at most one digit in its source code. You can use your chosen digit more than once however.* Your code has 1, 2, 3, 5, 6.

Comment: ah my bad, will edit